# Why MyEtherWallet and ethjs-signer produce different signatures for the same transaction?

Tags: solidity, web3js, myetherwallet

The following code, using `ethjs-signer`,

```
var privateKey = "0x0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef";

var transaction = {
    "nonce": 0,
    "gasPrice": "230000000000",
    "gasLimit": "21000",
    "to": '0xFCAd0B19bB29D4674531d6f115237E16AfCE377c',
    "value": "1000000000000000000",
    "data": "0x0123abcd"
}


var ethjsSigner = require("ethjs-signer");
console.log(ethjsSigner.sign(transaction, privateKey));
```

Produce this signature:

```
0xf8708085358d117c0082520894fcad0b19bb29d4674531d6f115237e16afce377c880de0b6b3a7640000840123abcd1ba04e289b471dd4469d5080ce3726b8359d5b0c649e012bbbdde53f9b6580ad21a2a0333663ea96846c112f3878705c8c24a763d1fbf8f97c174d26e350c7ef0d7263
```

The same transaction on MyEtherWallet produces this signature:

```
0xf8708085358d117c0082520894fcad0b19bb29d4674531d6f115237e16afce377c880de0b6b3a7640000840123abcd25a032dbcf46a64b9892df24d8b961d2a52fd66b1dabd3a0d96940fd6795c01d8711a01b86df9475de7451554557d87b69456e3fa95aa5375584bf63d1ffd647a225d9
```

Why are those signatures different?

Answer (score 2):

It appears the prior doesn't have the chainid which prevents transactions from being replayed on both chains. MyEtherWallet does.